# Capture clicks made in external jquery ui modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm loading a jQuery UI dialog window, which has some thumbnail images in. On click of an image, I want to return the id of the selected image.

I think I can achieve that using data attributes quite easily. The problem I'm having is that due to the thumbnails being loaded from an external page, I can't capture the click (.image-select) due to the DOM already being loaded. I think this is the case anyway. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Here's the code currently:

```
(function($) {

    $('#opener').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });

    $('#dialog').load('/account/images/thumbnails/').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 560,
        width: 670
    });

    $('.image-select').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).data('id'));
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Any tips or alternative methods of achieving this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` function accepts a callback to be executed after load.

```
(function($) {

$('#opener').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});

$('#dialog').load('/account/images/thumbnails/', function(){
   $('.image-select').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
   }); //function added in callback
}).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 560,
    width: 670
});



})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

delegate the `on()` click event to document or closest static parent present in the document or call the click event inside the callback of `load()`.

```
 $(document).on('click','.image-select',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
 });
```

[links](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about `on` delegates